# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated

Tags: jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to test JAXB unmarshaller/marshaller. Here is my code

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClientUser.class.getPackage().getName());
```

And a code of my entity

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class ClientUser {
    private String name;

    public ClientUser() {}

    public ClientUser(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Even if I add to the entity class a factory class

```
@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactory {
    ClientUser createPerson() {
        return new ClientUser();
    }
}
```

I'm still keep getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.example.ws.poc.entity" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "com.example.ws.poc.entity" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:335)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:431)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:394)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:298)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure they're in the same package?

Comment: What type of environment are you running in: Java SE, app server, OSGi?

Comment: No OSGi, only Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 4):

A JAXB implementation doesn't do package scanning.  If you boot strap from a package name, JAXB is going to look for an `ObjectFactory` (annotated with `@XmlRegistry`) or a `jaxb.index` file that contains short class names each on a new line.

If you don't have these two items you can create the `JAXBContext` on the domain classes themselves.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class);
```

Comment: The OP seems to have the `ObjectFactory` and he creates the context using the package name as a context path: `JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ClientUser.class.getPackage().getName());`. If `ObjectFactory` is in the same package as `ClientUser`, this must work.

Comment: @lexicore - It will definitely work if they are in the same package. In general though when starting from Java classes I recommend people bootstrap from classes or `jaxb.index` instead of an `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: I know, I know. :) `ObjectFactory` is a much more complex construct. However, this does not answer OP's question. He has a problem despite seemingly doing the right thing. The only other issue I can imagine is classloading (which I don't believe is the case here).

Comment: @lexicore -  The provider is coming up in the `com.sun.xml.bind` package (the RI) and not as `com.sun.internal.xml.bind` (version included in the JRE.  Which may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the context from the type of the class you want to deserialize. See below:

```
public class XmlDeserializer implements Deserializer {
  public <T> T deserialize(String input, Class<T> outputType)
    throws DeserializationException {
    try {
      JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(outputType);
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
      StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
      return outputType.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader));
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      throw new DeserializationException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
}
```